# Mail keeps setting "Save drafts on the server" checked

Tags: mail.app, gmail

I open "Preferences" in Mail, uncheck "Store drafts on server" and save (Gmail account). However, when I open the preferences again, the "Store drafts on server" (or whatever it says in English version) is checked again.
It really pisses me off. How can turn it off permanently?

I use OS X Mavericks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another good option that fixed the problem for me is as follows:

1. Quit Mail.app.
2. Log into Gmail in your favorite web browser.
3. Click on the gear menu and select **Settings**.
4. Click on the **Labels** tab.
5. Under **System Labels**, next to **Drafts**, click on **show if unread** and uncheck the **Show in IMAP** box. Now disable **Store draft messages on the server**.
6. Launch Mail.app.
7. Select **Mail** → **Preferences…**
8. Click on the **Accounts** button in the toolbar.
9. Click once on the account name and then click the **Mailbox Behaviors** tab.
10. Uncheck the **Store draft messages on the server** box.
11. Close the window and opt to save your changes when prompted.

<sup>**Source:** [Apple Support Communities: Mavericks Mail app and Gmail Drafts folder](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23500944#23500944)</sup>

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: Had the same problem. This fixed it for me, thanks!

Comment: Any solution for the same problem but not using Gmail as the e-mail service?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Mavericks? This is probably related to the MANY Gmail related problems that have cropped up since it's release.

You are in luck though, as Apple has just released an update to solve many of said problems.

http://www.macrumors.com/2013/11/07/apple-releases-mail-update-for-mavericks-to-address-gmail-issues/

Comment: Yes, I use Mavericks. I'll try the update and see how it works.

Comment: The update has not helped.